# Is this a demodulated signal?

Tags: radio, frequency-modulation, demodulation, detector

### 1st attempt

I have a problem. I built the FM demodulator circuit, but i am not sure if this signal is demodulated. This was my first attempt which following an answer, resulted in a 2nd attempt further down.

[image]
This is my input - fm modulated signal and output :
[image]

---

### EDIT - 2nd attempt following advice in an answer:

[image]

This is my input - fm modulated signal and output :

[image]

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: Maybe? There isn't really any way to tell anything from those graphs.

Comment: ahh nope. just looks attenuated

Comment: Can't see much difference at that resolution apart from amplitude. Post the schematic of the circuit you're testing

Comment: Ok, I'm adding circuit diagram.

Comment: This is ratio detector, I mean I try build...

Comment: did you see this http://aaronscher.com/Circuit_a_Day/week_by_week/August_2016_FM_Foster_Seeley_detector/FM_Foster_Seeley_Detector.html

Comment: Yes, I try simulate scheme in LTspice, but doesn't work and I try solve it.

Comment: This file http://aaronscher.com/Circuit_a_Day/week_by_week/August_2016_FM_Foster_Seeley_detector/documents/Foster-Seeley-Simulation.asc  works in my LTspice without any problem

Comment: The input signal doesn't look like FM for a start.

Comment: As far as I can see Foster-Seeley FM detector is similar to ratio detector. Am I wrong?

Comment: I don't see you defining the coupling constants of the transformer L1-L4. It won't work without that.

Comment: Is "K L4 L1 L2 1" this formula wrong?

Comment: Reverse your modifications and, if you must include some change of heart make sure that this is unambiguously clear. I didn't spend my time making an answer to you for you to move the goalposts and make my answer look silly. So, fix your question back to respect my answer and I'll consider whether it's worthwhile helping you with your modified circuit. I mean, it's not even clear that you have actually read my answer!!

Comment: @Andyaka sorry, I didn't want to do anything wrong. I only want solve the problem. Thanks for the good advice in answering my question. It helped me a bit too.

Comment: I've edited your question to make things clearer. Try making k = 0.5 to 0.8 instead of 0.999. And try making R1 much bigger (say 1 kohm). Not saying it will solve things but it might make the demodulated signal clearer.

Comment: @Chuckyy - actually it won't work with perfect coupling - the ratio detector relies upon loose coupling to give a phase shift between the output across C2 and the reference voltage from L4.

Comment: So what I should correct?

Comment: Try one single k value of `L1 L2 L3 0.5` and see what happens

Comment: @Chuckyy are we done here? Did you manage to resolve this?

Comment: @Andyaka yes, the layout looked like in the edited post, I changed the values of some elements: C3, R1, R2 and the voltage source V1.

Comment: Did you get success? I'm asking because you ought to consider closing down this Q and A session. Maybe if you got it to work you can add your own answer to explain what you did.

Comment: @Andyaka sorry i forgot about this post. I am closing the thread!

Comment: Hold on... if you have this problem fixed then either you should accept my answer if it helped or add your own answer that explains the fix. Please don't short-change this site.

Comment: I understand and sorry for any problems on my part. Your answer was certainly inspiring to further solve the problem. I found the answer helpful. I will try to add what I did and what I finally finished the project with.

Comment: That's the best way because someone else might find this useful.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you should try and draw schematics so that they can be displayed properly: -

[image]

Secondly, you should not use the Rser statement because it hides the important fact that there is 60 Ω in series with the AC source. Well, I say it hides it; I'm not actually sure what it does with LTspice so, better to explicitly show it as a resistor.

And, with Rser at 60 Ω, L = 40 μH and C = 1 nF you get a rather shallow band pass filter effect that, might as well not be present at all: -

[image]

Then, the main killer is that you have applied a coupling factor of unity to all the inductors in your transformer, so, it won't work properly. Try something around 0.5 instead of 1.